# Friends of a friend can see my post when my friend comments or likes, even if I am not my friend's friends

Tags: facebook, privacy

If I post something on Facebook and a friend comments on it or likes it, how is it that other people who are friends of the comment writers or likers, but not friends of mine, can see it?

Surely this is against the point of me having a private profile, isn’t it?

Answer (score 8):

It all depends on **your** privacy settings.

The default for actions is often that "friends of friends" can see actions.

You can control the visibility of a post when you post it. Make sure the default action for that is "Friends" only. This can be done on the [Privacy Settings and Tools page](http://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy) via the "Who can see my stuff?" option:

[image: Who can see my stuff?]

Then go to the [Timeline and Tagging Settings page](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=timeline) and make sure that the "Who can see what others post on your timeline?" option is set to "Friends" only rather than "Friends of friends".

[image: Who can see things on my timeline?]

These options change regularly so it's always worth double checking the settings and making sure only those people you want to interact with are able to see what you post.

Comment: That setting is for posts that other people make on your timeline.  The setting for your posts is not there, it is at the bottom of each post (they are each set individually).

Comment: @mark4o - true, but the OP is asking about comments from friends.

Comment: But the visibility of your post is controlled by the setting on the post, not the one in Privacy Settings.

Comment: @mark4o - I think the fact that your friend comments and you have "friends of friends" set trumps that.

Comment: Super answer. Muchas Gracias!!

Comment: I think this should be tested. I can imagine that when a friend comments on your post their friends will see his/her comment (and the related post as well).